# adb shell push image to recent or downloads folders not on sdcard

Tags: adb, file-system, shell

I want to push images to one of this folders:

[image]

with shell command. But file only appears on `sdcard` folder

My last tries was:

```
adb push C:\Users\User\Pictures\girl.jpg /data/media/0/Pictures/
adb push C:\Users\User\Pictures\girl.jpg /sdcard/Pictures
adb push C:\Users\User\Pictures\girl.jpg /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
```

Comment: Recent is not a folder, just a list of files recently opened. Dawnloads is `/sdcard/Download` or `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.